# How to remove account using polkadotjs? What function should I call to forget an account?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-front-end, polkadot-js-extension, wallet

I added a new account using this command in PolkadotJS.

```js
const { pair, json } = keyring.addUri(mnemonic, 'myStr0ngP@ssworD', { name: 'mnemonic acc' });
```

And now, I want to forget the account.
I used `keyring.forgetAddress`, but it doesn't really remove the account.
I always load accounts using `keyring.getAccounts()` after `forgetAddress`.

[image]

For example, how does the **Forget Account** action work in the PolkadotJS extension?
What function or API is called?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the method to use here is `forgetAccount`, not `forgetAddress`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @INcre Please, mark the question as resolved then.

Comment: I am not able to check two answers at once. Do you know how to do that? @Adam

Comment: Ah, ok, I missed Bruno's answer. Nevermind then.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful!!!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what Adam said.

According to the docs:

- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/ui-keyring/start/addresses#removing-an-address

`forgetAddress` mirrors `forgetAccount` and if we look in the code we will see the minor difference in the two:

```js
  public forgetAddress (address: string): void {
    this.addresses.remove(this._store, address);
  }
```

- https://github.com/polkadot-js/ui/blob/b06e35bd032caf5e727f4cc36da29a71a53d3702/packages/ui-keyring/src/Keyring.ts#L128-L130

```js
  public forgetAccount (address: string): void {
    this.keyring.removePair(address);
    this.accounts.remove(this._store, address);
  }
```

- https://github.com/polkadot-js/ui/blob/b06e35bd032caf5e727f4cc36da29a71a53d3702/packages/ui-keyring/src/Keyring.ts#L123-L126

The reason you are still seeing the account when you call `getAccounts` is because `forgetAddress()` does not call `this.accounts.remove(this._store, address)` where as `forgetAccount()` does.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
Thank you very much. @Bruno